# Add product a product in Prestashop 1.6.10 from an API external?

Tags: php, oop, prestashop

Currently, I program a module for Prestashop 1.6.10 which is in the administration panel, using an external API and my problem is that I don't understand how to add a product in the database in back-office.

This is the code I have wrote :

```
public function Product() {
    if (empty($_GET['product'])) {
        return false;
    }

    switch($_GET['product']) {
        case 'add' :
            $product = new ProductCore();
            $product->id_shop_default = 1;
            $product->id_manufacturer = 1;
            $product->id_supplier = 1;
            $product->reference = "adding_product";
            $product->supplier_reference = "";
            $product->location = "";
            $product->width = "0.00000";
            $product->height = "0.00000";
            $product->depth = "0.00000";
            $product->weight = "0.00000";
            $product->quantity_discount = "0";
            $product->ean13 = "0";
            $product->upc = "";
            $product->cache_is_pack = "0";
            $product->cache_has_attachments = "0";
            $product->is_virtual = "0";
            $product->save();
            $product->add();
            break;
        /** Product suppression.
        case 'del' :
            if (Product::existsInDatabase()) {

            }
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I use the "product" object but it is not work and I don't why :(

Could someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a problem in my code : the function Product is not executed by the controller adminController when I click on "Adding a product" from the catalog page.

Moreover, the function works if I force Prestashop to execute the function but Prestashop don't like this because I create a bug and the module is not accessible.

[UPDATE 01-09-2017 at 17:35 GMT]

Currently, the code is working, but I have this problem now ... I think it's about the language parameters when I create the product, but I do not do what I need to do to solve this problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZW1A.png)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Product` class instead of `ProductCore`.

`save` function is enough to save product in DB. It is not necessary to use `add` function after that.

If product values are incorrect it will display an error. But you should activate DEBUG MODE first:  [Activate Prestashop Debug Mode](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/prestashop-16/enable-error-reporting)

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code.

```
{
        $object = new Product();
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if (array_key_exists($key, $object) && $key != 'id_product') {
                $object->{$key} = $value;
            }
        }

        $languages = Language::getLanguages(false);
        $class_vars = get_class_vars(get_class($object));
        $fields = array();
        if (isset($class_vars['definition']['fields'])) {
            $fields = $class_vars['definition']['fields'];
        }
        foreach ($fields as $field => $params) {
            if (array_key_exists('lang', $params) && $params['lang']) {
                foreach ($languages as $language) {
                    $value = '';

                    if (Tools::getIsset($field . '_' . (int)$language['id_lang'])) {
                        $value = Tools::getValue($field . '_' . (int)$language['id_lang']);
                    } elseif (isset($object->{$field}[(int)$language['id_lang']])) {
                        $value = $object->{$field}[(int)$language['id_lang']];
                    }
            foreach ($languages as $lang) {
                if (Tools::getIsset($field . '_' . (int)$lang['id_lang']) && Tools::getValue($field . '_' . (int)$lang['id_lang']) != '')
                    $value = Tools::getValue($field . '_' . (int)$lang['id_lang']);
            }
                    if ($field == 'description_short') {
                        $short_description_limit = Configuration::get('PS_PRODUCT_SHORT_DESC_LIMIT')
                            ? Configuration::get('PS_PRODUCT_SHORT_DESC_LIMIT') : 400;
                        $object->{$field}[(int)$language['id_lang']] = strip_tags(
                            $this->clipLongText(
                                $value,
                                '',
                                $short_description_limit,
                                false
                            )
                        );
                    } else {
                        $object->{$field}[(int)$language['id_lang']] = $value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach ($languages as $language) {
            $keywords = '';
            if (Tools::getIsset('meta_keywords_' . $language['id_lang'])) {
                $keywords = Tools::getValue('meta_keywords_' . $language['id_lang']);
            } elseif (isset($object->meta_keywords[$language['id_lang']])) {
                $keywords = $object->meta_keywords[$language['id_lang']];
            }
            $keywords = $this->cleanMetaKeywords(
                Tools::strtolower($keywords)
            );
            $object->meta_keywords[$language['id_lang']] = $keywords;
        }

        $_POST['width'] = (!Tools::getIsset('width')) ? '0' : str_replace(',', '.', Tools::getValue('width'));
        $_POST['height'] = (!Tools::getIsset('height')) ? '0' : str_replace(',', '.', Tools::getValue('height'));
        $_POST['depth'] = (!Tools::getIsset('depth')) ? '0' : str_replace(',', '.', Tools::getValue('depth'));
        $_POST['weight'] = (!Tools::getIsset('weight')) ? '0' : str_replace(',', '.', Tools::getValue('weight'));

        if (Tools::getIsset('unit_price') != null) {
            $object->unit_price = str_replace(',', '.', Tools::getValue('unit_price'));
        }

        $object->available_for_order = (int)Tools::getValue('available_for_order');
        $object->show_price = $object->available_for_order ? 1 : (int)Tools::getValue('show_price');
        $object->on_sale = (int)Tools::getValue('on_sale');
        $object->online_only = (int)Tools::getValue('online_only');

        $ecotaxTaxRate = Tax::getProductEcotaxRate();
        if ($ecotax = Tools::getValue('ecotax')) {
            $_POST['ecotax'] = Tools::ps_round($ecotax / (1 + $ecotaxTaxRate / 100), 6);
        }
        if (Tools::getIsset('ecotax') != null) {
            $object->ecotax = str_replace(',', '.', Tools::getValue('ecotax'));
        }
        $object->add();
    }
```